# Jsoup: Optimal way of checking whether a <div> has an ID

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am able to iterate through all div elements in a document, using **getElementsByTag("div")**.

Now I want to build a list of only div elements that have the attribute "id" (i.e. div elements with attribute "class" shouldn't be in the list).

Intuitively, I was thinking of checking something like this:

```
  if (divElement.attr("id") != "")
    add_to_list(divElement);
```

Is my approach correct at all?

Is there a more optimal way of testing for having the "id" attribute? (the above uses string comparison for every element in the DOM document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Elements divsWithId = doc.select("div[id]");
for(Element element : divsWithId){
    // do something
}
```

**Reference:**

- [JSoup > Selector Syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var all_divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divs_with_id = [];

for (var i = 0; i < all_divs.length; i++)
  if (all_divs[i].hasAttribute("id"))
    divs_with_id.push(all_divs[i]);
```

Comment: Is this Javascript? :)  Jsoup is in Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Pardon.... kinda missed it in the title of the question. But all of the methods I was using are DOM, so they should be alike in all languages.